# How to determine if an iOS device is stopped or moving (driving)

Tags: ios, gps, accelerometer, core-location, core-motion

We have an App that is used around vehicles. It's not supposed to be used whilst the vehicle is in motion (laws & health & safety requirements). We can lock the device to only use this one App through Guided Access but what we really need to do is also lock the app when the vehicle is moving. Ideally, some sort of lock screen will come up saying that you shouldn't be using it whilst moving and it will stay there until the vehicle stops.

Now we know that the GPS on an iOS device is not that accurate so I'm thinking something in CoreMotion (possibly combined with the GPS) would do the trick. Essentially we want to activate this Drive Safe mode when the device is moving faster than 10kph.

Can this be done? How can we prevent false flags (GPS randomly jumping locations - as it's known to do) Is CoreMotion the way to do this?

Ultimately it would be great if Apple introduced such a thing in the OS to stop distracted driving (texting/FB/tweeting while driving) but I was hoping for at least this one app, we can do this.

Thanks in advance for any pointers or tips.

Comment: I think you can use accelerometer sensor. not sure but read in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer

Comment: GpS on on iphone4/4s and probably on iphone5 too, is one of the best GPS chips on the market. you can super reliably determine by Gps if the device is moving or not. have you tried?

Comment: @Jordan M: you get the solution? If you already have implemented then can you please share that here? Thanks in advance....

Comment: Sorry - no solution just yet but we've delayed the feature until we can get a better technical fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the location manager sensitivity?

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
```

Also, keep in mind that devices with Cellular **MAY** also help, as the location manager will also try to triangulate the users location by bouncing off of the cell towers.

According to Apple's documentation "Core Location" doesn't just use GPS, it also uses Cellular Towers and WiFi :

> The Core Location framework lets you locate the current position of the device and use that information in your app. The framework uses information obtained from the built-in cellular, Wi-Fi, or GPS hardware to triangulate a location fix for the device. It reports that location to your code and, depending on how you configure the service, also provides periodic updates as it receives new or improved data.

[Apple Core Location Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Comment: the first part of your answer is ok. but what the hell has cell tower based locating with moving detection to do?

Comment: Before GPS was widely used in Cell Phone, location based services used to use Mobile Position Systems, here's an article : http://searchengineland.com/cell-phone-triangulation-accuracy-is-all-over-the-map-14790